# alternative ways to say "who are you?"?

Tags: translation

For saying who are you? I understand you can say

Kimi wa dare nanda? or Anata wa dare? and similars.

Then what does Silver Fang say here?

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1M6C35Hxu1Q&t=2m22s

What I hear is "Dare ja ne .. kimi wa" 
I guess I'm misshearing a lot because as far as I know "ja ne" it's a way to say good bye so it doesnt make sense to be there? What is he saying exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not mishearing it. The じゃ is a corrupted form of だ common to accented speech in Japan. 関西弁 does something similar, but uses や. The ね works as similarly to か (question-indicating sentence final particle), but I would think of it as a softer, more colloquial か.

(In Shoko's comment on this answer, she suggests that it feels a little bit arrogant and is most likely to come from an old man.)

If きみはだれですか is "Who are you?", you can think of だれじゃね。。。きみは as "Who da... hell're you?" or similar.

Comment: `The ね is odd` -> 「誰じゃね？」はおかしくないです。「誰だね？」と同じです。この「ね」は「か？」じゃないです（「誰だか？」「誰じゃか？」とは言わないので）。この場合の「じゃ」はアニメのお年寄りの話し方（役割語・老人語）だと思います。

Comment: @Shoko アニメだけじゃなく、漫画でもゲームでもライトノベルでも使われることが多いと思います。

Comment: @Nothingatall あ、そうですね。アニメだけじゃないですね。多分、ドラマでも。時代劇とか。いろんなフィクションで見られますね。

Comment: Isn't じゃね short for じゃない. It's common on anime for ない to become ね

Comment: @FelipeOliveira That would be じゃねえ. This じゃね is just dialect/fictional old people copula じゃ + sentence-ending particle ね.

Comment: @Shoko - "odd to me"と"odd"と違いがあります。おかしい以上、珍しいとか聞いたことないとか意味が。

それより、私の答えの後でその「この「ね」は「か」みたい」ありましたよ。

Comment: @FelipeOliveira ～じゃね{HHH}？ is short for じゃない？ (a recent slang speech), but ～じゃね{LLH}？ or ～じゃね{LLL}⤴？ is じゃ + ね.

Comment: 「誰だね？」「何だね？」「何かね？」「どこだね？」「そうかね？」などの、質問文に付く「ね」は、さほど珍しくはないと思います。「誰だ‌​ね？」は、‌​「誰だ？」に終助詞「ね」がつい‌​たもの‌です。明鏡国語辞典に‌​、「ね 【終助詞】③《質問の文に‌​付いて》質問・確認・反問・疑念などに尊大‌​さを添える。『今日は何日かね』『明日は来‌​てくれるかね』『そんな手に誰が乗りますか‌​ね』▶質問・反問の意では、主として年配の‌​男性が使う。」とあります。確かに、このセリフ‌​を言ってる人はおじいさんで、ちょっと‌​エラソーな感じがしますよね。

Comment: @shoko nothing at all william - rem broken headphones , should I mark it as accepted? or is it wrong?

Comment: @brokenheadphones I don't know how to show accentuation the way you did, but usually goes like [俺はあんたの友達じゃねぞ」 and also words like かこいい becomes かけ~.  I hear that a lot in anime. But the regular ね and the ね in じゃね are definitelly a bit different. In portuguese the first would be né, and the second would be nê

Comment: @FelipeOliveira http://meta.japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/806/how-should-i-format-my-questions-on-japanese-language-se

Comment: @brokenheadphones so the one I hear would be じゃね​{HL} . and かけ{HL} (why the first doesnt work T_T)

Comment: @FelipeOliveira Japanese doesn't have broad "e" and narrow "e", only one "e". But indeed かっけえ usually renders into a broader vowel as you said, in varying degree.

Comment: @FelipeOliveira The system only recognizes character length, so you have to input {HHL}. (But the right way to mark it in Japanese accentology would be だれじゃ{HLLL}ね{H} in this case.)

Comment: @brokenheadphones I think that maybe whenever they change じゃない into じゃねえ they use the "double e" sound, cause that's how I hear it at least.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/55340/discussion-between-broken-headphones-and-felipe-oliveira).

Comment: @Pablo - Shoko is taking issue with the fact that I said that the ね sounded odd to me as a sentence final particle (終助詞) in place of か.